# Navigator longitude and latitude

Tags: javascript

How can I pull out longitude and latitude values from getCurrentPosition() function?

```
getPosition() {


    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => position.coords.longitude);
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => position.coords.latitude);

    return [longitude, latitude];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `callback`:

```
function getPosition(options) {
     if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) 
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
}
function errorCallback(error) {
     console.error(error);
} 
function successCallback(position) {
     console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
}
```